# Showing the latest news page on the navigation menu in Silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

I have a `NewsPage` type and in the navigation I want to show an entry called `Latest News` which will render the latest `NewsPage` (according to `Created` field). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your Template for the navigation you should be able to insert the link to the latest NewsPage inside a list item inside the ul for the navigation.

To get the latest NewsPage you will need to write a function inside your Page Controller that returns the latest news page. Here is an example.

```
function GetLatestNews()
{
     return DataObject::get_one('NewsPage', '', '', 'Created DESC');
}
```

Then inside your template for the navigation you should do something like this.

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <% control Menu(1) %>
        <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link">$MenuTitle.XML</a></li>
    <% end_control %>
    <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$GetLatestNews.Link">Latest News</a></li>
</ul>
```

That will insert the link at the end of the navigation. If you want to insert the link into a specific position you can use the $Pos inside the control to check which position it is at. Here is an example:<% if Pos

```
 <ul id="navigation">
    <% control Menu(1) %>
          <% if Pos = 2 %>
              <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$GetLatestNews.Link">Latest News</a></li>
          <% end_if %>
    <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link">$MenuTitle.XML</a></li>

    <% end_control %>

</ul>
```

The above will insert the link at the second position inside the navigation.